# How can I put html div elements beneath each other when the screen gets smaller?

Tags: html, css, position

I'm developing an online platform but I can't seem to get the placement right on three of my div elements. The elements are placed [next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oY37.png) by default for bigger screens. However, when the screen gets smaller, the elements [get cramped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCX29.png). I would like to be able to place the three boxes beneath each other when the screen gets smaller with an @media query from CSS. I tried changing the position attribute for the divs' class but this didn't work. My current code is as follows:

#### HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="frameContainer">
        <div class="frameItem">
          <h3>Block 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <button class="learnMore" type="button" name="button">Lees meer</button>
        </div>
        <div class="frameItem" id="middleFrame">
          <h3>Block 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <button class="learnMore" type="button" name="button">Lees meer</button>
        </div>
        <div class="frameItem">
          <h3>Block 3</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          <button class="learnMore" type="button" name="button">Lees meer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

#### CSS:

```
.frameItem {
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 20px 25px 25px 25px;
  background-color: var(--frameBackGround);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow:
    0px 10px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }

.frameContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 7.5%;
}

#middleFrame {
  margin: 15px 2% 0 2%;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could get the three boxes beneath each other using the @media query? Which attribute should I manipulate using the media query? All help is most apriciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.frameContainer {
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Add this and it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, unfortunately, now it shows up as two columns in both big and small screens. Any idea how I can make sure that it stays in 3 columns in big screens and 1 column with small screens (I think the column-count attribute is not applicable here. I tried it and it turned out even more of a mess).

Comment: I needed to adjust the percentages in order to make the spacing work properly. Thakns a lot for your suggestion!